# What are differences between Druid and ElasticSearch ? What are advantages for both?

Tags: elasticsearch, druid

I am pretty new with Druid and I don't get my answers regarding the comparison with ElasticSearch. I found this link: [druid vs Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119568/druid-vs-elasticsearch) but it does not give the differences and advantages.

Can anyone explain me that or give me some links that I didn't find on google ?

Thanks in advance.

J

Comment: It's apples and pears. Druid is for aggregating data, Elasticsearch is a search engine. It's not a useful comparison. Elasticsearch could be compared to e.g.: Solr, Sphinx or barebones Lucene. Druid is pretty much alone in the aggregation department afaik. Let us know what you want to accomplish and I'm sure you get a more satisfying answer.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am trying to build a lambda architecture where I have to select a data base for my serving layer. Indeed, on this serving layer I want to request in real time a large amount of data in order to filter, do some aggregation and other computations. I selected ElasticSearch instead of Cassandra and MongoDB but some of my collegues indicated me Druid. However, ElasticSearch also does aggregation. Thus, is Druid better than ElasticSearch for aggregation and filters ?

Comment: if your colleagues will help you with the support of the Druid, it is better to choose for Druid, but I advise you to try it out first. At druid too high entry threshold.

"Druid is extremely difficult, complex and time-consuming to initially set up, and operate in production. So unless you really need to ingest 1M+ events/sec AND you have a dedicated team to take care of it, just use Elasticsearch"
https://github.com/Banno/druid-docker/issues/3#issuecomment-190749607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Druid commiters have a [nice short text](http://druid.io/docs/latest/comparisons/druid-vs-elasticsearch.html) - with some bias, of course - about this. Maybe will help you.

In summary, Druid is great with timeseries data because it have [Roll-up funcionality](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.1.1/design/index.html#roll-up) and is based on [Historical Nodes](http://druid.io/docs/0.9.1.1/design/historical.html).

ElasticSearch is a full-text search database on top of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). Have features to Recomendations and Data Mining like [More Like This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) and [Fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) query.